# New version of display inline not working-mine is just not consistent

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I know the question about display:inline not working has been asked multiple times for varying circumstances, but I can't find my problem. It works but doesn't work, even in the same paragraph.
I'm using a tooltip, which works great on desktop and mobile.
Here is the page: https://coachcaudlecares.org/llltest.html
Here is the css:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display:inline;
  color: red;
  
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #999999;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Here is a sample paragraph in html:

```
<p>During Jim&apos;s <div class="tooltip">toddler<span class="tooltiptext">Toddler Jim with mother, Ethyl Green Caudle, circa 1934<br/><img src=/images/toddlerjimandmom.jpg width="134"></span></div> years, his parents divorced. His mother, who had been adopted by Grady &quot;Grandpa Russell&quot; Sr., owner of the local <div class="tooltip">Russell Transfer Company<span class="tooltiptext">Russell Transfer vehicle<br><img src=/images/russelltransfer.png width="266"></span></div>, and Ida Jane House Russel, became a single mom during one of the most-difficult times in our country&apos;s history, the Great Depression.
```

I can't see any difference in the code that would make one display inline and one not. What am I missing?
Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: It is not clear from your question what problem you have. Can you clarify what you specifically want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `<div>` elements inside of `<p>` elements—it's invalid HTML. `<p>` elements can only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content), but `<div>` elements are [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content).

Browsers will often do unexpected things when they encounter invalid HTML. In this case, many browsers will close any open paragraph elements when they encounter an opening `<div>` tag.

If you need to wrap text inside a paragraph with an element that doesn't have semantic meaning, you should use a `<span>` element instead. It's the phrasing content equivalent of a `<div>` element.

```
<!-- this is invalid -->
<p>Lorem ipsum <div class="tooltip">dolor</div></p>

<!-- use spans instead -->
<p>Lorem ipsum <span class="tooltip">dolor</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution. I didn't realize I could use one <span> element inside another. I appreciate this so much!